# Improving the readability of PL/SQL for identifying the LOOPs and Individual blocks

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am relatively new to PL/SQL (Oracle). I am able to complete my assignment successfully. Having followed Modular programming, I divided my program into small PL/SQL blocks. Also I have nested `BEGIN-END` in my code. (To handle exceptions)

When my code base started to grow, I could see many nested blocks inside, and I am unable to identify the corresponding `END` for every `BEGIN` block .(When the blocks are bigger). The same case with the nested `FOR LOOP`s too. I agree there's no curly brackets in PL/SQL.

I improved the indentation of my code to the best of my ability, and to some extent the code is readable now. But still, if anyone else wanted to read my code, I have a feeling that my code may not be easy to traverse.

Do you guys provide some suggestions to solve my issue?

Comment: did you try formatting with any IDE, like toad or sql developer?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code that you feel is not readable, but don't know how to improve?

Comment: did you try named PL /SQL BLOCKS.?

Comment: sounds a nice plan, let me try it out. Thank you!

Comment: This is part of the reason why packages exist. Many nested PL/SQL blocks almost certainly mean you're doing something strange

Comment: LABELS in PL/SQL are official for loops. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm#BABIFDBA

Comment: the user here uses a package only, and have already modularised them having multiple procedures inside it. his main concern was moving from braces matching to pl sql blocks. I think, this question is really valid! Please re analyse this. Some times. naming the pl sql blocks will always give favour.

Comment: It is better, if some one in Oracle expertise review it, rather just a general SQL specialist! There is nothing misleading factor here!

Comment: EXIT WHEN is no way related to GOTO. pleade go through the Oracle docs.

Comment: Try using **Toad**. It has support for **nesting** SQL Procedures. It makes code very readable. See this snapshot. I also got confused and toad solved me this nesting issue. [See the Snapshot](http://i68.tinypic.com/201kdc.png) -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <<outer_loop>>
 LOOP
   <<<block1>>
   BEGIN
       i := i + 1;
       j := 0;
       <<inner_loop>>
       LOOP
         -- Your Statements
         EXIT inner_loop WHEN (j > 5);
         EXIT outer_loop WHEN ((i * j) > 15);
       END LOOP inner_loop;
   END block1;
 END LOOP outer_loop;
```

Try using `LABELS` (embedded between angled brackets). This should help you!
Your can look for the label names, for where the block/loop starts or ends!

Actually, this kind of Label can be used for `GOTO` too

But dont over use it, as it also confuses you :)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input,I shall add this to critical/lengthy parts of my code.

Comment: Most welcome! Good day!

Comment: Coding `EXIT outer_loop WHEN` like that is basically the same as a `GOTO` statement.  Personally I'm not scared to use `GOTO` in my code but that's because I understand what it actually does.  My concern is for people who write arbitrary re-directions of control but who think they're not producing spaghetti code because they don't type the keyword `GOTO`.

Comment: @APC, I understand MaheswaranRavisankar's point. Am using this with caution, moving from C++ (UNIX), we used to search for matching brace to trace logics. Not just me, many of us, that's why I worried. I had to jump in to give a start to this project, and it is going to be maintained by some other sooner! Glad I followed all standards & I make the code readable. Even though I modularised most logics, there're few things(LOOPS, IF-ELSE) that has to be lengthy.. business wise. And that's why I am here. So, Maheswaran's idea really helps at those places! Thanks for being so Quick and Thorough..

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following solutions. I guess a combination of them should help.

1) Turn your inner PL/SQL Blocks into procedures. This will shorten the blocks.

2) Use a PL/SQL Editor (SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer, TOAD, SQL Navigator are all quite popular among the community.) to view the code. Each editor has its own solution such as indicating matching begins and ends with brackets, code folding etc...

Comment: I agree that writing nested procedures is a good way to make the code more readable (provided the procedures are well-named).  Modularity also promotes re-use which can make the code base shorter, but definitely aids readability by highlighting common functionality.